# iPhone FBConnect, dashboard.addnews

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, fbconnect, facebook-feed

How to add news via FBConnect?
I have the following code:

```
NSString *newsBody = @"[{\"message\": \"News message\" }]";
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:newsBody forKey:@"news"];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.dashboard.addnews" params:params dataParam:nil];
```

After I sent the request I received the success responce. But I can't see the new news in the facebook account.

Also, I tried to add full info into news parameter (http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Dashboard.addNews):

```
NSString *newsBody = @"[{\"message\": \"News message\",\"action_link\": {\"text\": \"link text\",
\"href\": \"http: //google.com\"} }]";
```

But this request returns error.
Any ideas?

Comment: First I thought that it's permission issue. But regarding the permission list (http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions) I don't need any permissions to add news. Anybody????!!!!!

Comment: I think I found the reason. FB developers forgot to add "uid" parameter to the FB request. But after I added it the news is still do not shows up in the dashboard. WHAT A HELL!!! It's so trivial task!!! ANYBODY???!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The FBStreamDialog should be used to publish the news. It means that the custom interface cannot be used for this purposes. :( 
Also, just wanted to say that FBConnect it's a one big mess!! Currently fighting with the bug when after clicking Cancel button in the FB dialog the dialog firing the event dialogDidSucceed but not dialogDidCancel. Such a big mess!!!